# css margins exceeding page layout (height)

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

Here's the link to the page thats causing a frustation for me : [www.kbay.in](http://kbay.in)

I tried looking up everything in the style.css file...'but it seems that I always come out with blank results'...as you can see the page exceeds even after the footer ends...I have no idea what it is....any help would be grateful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, your `<div id="header">` contains `<ul id="menu12">`. Within that, there is;

```
<li class="menu_right"><div class="dropdown_3columns align_right"><div class="col_1"><table>
```

within this table there are a load of rows which is causing the page to be so long. Deleteing this stops it from stretching as much as it does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the table in the div.dropdown_3columns in the header ul.

```
$('#header #menu12 .dropdown_3columns table').hide()
```

That .dropdown_3columns appears to be hanging out off-page (left:-999em) and taking enough vertical height to push your page below your footer.

If you want to see the culprit:

```
$('#header #menu12 .dropdown_3columns').css('left', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid off your hard coded widths

```
<div style="width: 1200px; min-width: 1200px;" class="page_margins_search">
```

And add overflow hidden to this class should work

```
.page_margins_search{
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
   width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: best practice is not to set stlyes in your markup, adding overflow hidden in firebug seems to work fine for me,